# NHibernate: Configure() in every page request?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been reading many books on NHibernate and have noticed how the Configure() is implemented. In the books that method is called every time the application is run in a console application. Most of the ASP.NET examples online call  Configure() on every page request. I think this will have alot of overhead since NHibernate must be configured on every request. Does it matter if NHibernate is configured on every page request? If not, how would someone save the configuration - application wide in asp.net mvc?

Comment: *"Most of the ASP.NET examples online call Configure() on every page request."* **What?** Where are those examples?

Comment: calling Configure and so the SessionFactory for each request is a Worst practice example.

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate is designed to be configured once per application start. In the case of a console program, that's every time you run the program. In the case of an ASP.NET application, that's every time the application starts, firing the `Application.Start` event.

The `SessionFactory` NHibernate creates from `Configure()` is safe to be cached for the lifetime of the application and is thread-safe to create sessions repeatedly. There is no need to configure on every request.

In the most basic way, you can use a lazy-initialized static property to safely give you a singleton for your application to use:

```
public static class NHibernateSessions
{
    private static readonly Lazy<SessionFactory> lazyFactory;

    static NHibernateSessions
    {
        lazyFactory = new Lazy<SessionFactory >(
            () => NHibernateSessions.CreateSessionFactory());
    }

    public static SessionFactory Factory
    {
        get
        {
            return NHibernateSessions.lazyFactory.Value;
        }
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if(!NHibernateSessions.lazyFactory.IsValueCreated)
        {
            // Access the value to force initialization.
            var factory = lazyFactory.Value;
        }
    }

    private static SessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        // Add code here to configure and create factory.
    }
}
```

This code uses the `Lazy<T>` type, to ensure the initialization is thread-safe. You can then call `NHibernateSessions.Factory` to get the singleton factory with which to re-use throughout your application.

By default the factory is initialized on the first get of the `Factory` property. This means that for an ASP.NET application, the first request to attempt to use NHibernate will be a slow one. If this is a problem, you can force initialization when the application starts by calling the `Initialize()` method in an `Application.Start` event-handler.

Comment: please excuse my ignorance on this subject. What kind of global variable would I store the value in? It does not seem good to store the value in cache because the cache can be wiped out. How would I do that?

Comment: My term of "cache" doesn't refer to the ASP.NET cache - apologies if this is confusing; I've updated my answer with a little code to help you out.